# How to convert String inot a LocalDate object

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, java-time, localdate

I have a String value as follows

```
2018-12-05 18:11:27.187
```

How can I can convert it into a LocalDate object based on that format "MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss" ?

Comment: Dates don't have formats. Text representations of dates have formats.

Comment: Parse the `LocalDate` (abstraction with no specific format) and use `DateTimeFormatter` (String representation) to achieve the formatted result.

Comment: Please don't use archaic and confusing date formats.  The original string is the ONLY correct way to write out a date numerically.  (Dropping the milliseconds is fine, of course.)

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been addressed aman many times already,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `LocalDate` object is what it is. It has no format; it is an object with methods; these methods make it do stuff.

You can for example ask a localdate to return the year of the date it represents. You can also ask it to render itself as a string using some format. That string is then not a LocalDate (it is a String).

Furthermore, a localdate represents a date. Hence the name. 'hour' is not part of a date. `YYYY` is the pattern for week based year. You don't want that.

So, fixing your misconceptions, we end up with:

```
DateTimeFormatter inFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
DateTimeFormatter outFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime when = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-12-05 18:11:27.187", inFormat);
System.out.println(outFormat.format(when));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly you need to define the pattern of your current `Date and Time` input
2. Parse the current `Date and Time` to `LocalDateTime` class
3. Print the value to the new `Date and Time` format you want.

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-12-05 18:11:27.187", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"));

System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu HH:mm:ss")));
```

Comment: Thank you. The steps are very helpful.